# R: how to get xpath expression for the nested structure

Tags: regex, r, xpath

the following is the html codes:

```
<div class="grid1-4">
  <a class="largeButton javascript sponsorProject button orangeGrad" href="javascript:;">
  <div class="button">
  <div class="button progress">
     <div class="progressWrapper">
         <div class="meter">
            <div class="progress" style="width:52%"> </div>
         </div>
         <p class="progressText">
         <span>52% Raised of $20,000 Goal</span>
```

I want to extract the sentence around  at the very bottom of the codes - that is, `52% Raised of $20,000 Goal`.

what is the xpath expression for that? I googled and searched for hints but couldn't get much out of it...:(. I even used firebug to find xpath expression yet still, no progress...

thank you

PS: due to the nature of my project, I CANNOT write

```
  //p[@class="progressText"]//span
```

the xpath expression HAS TO INVOLVE

```
  <div class="grid1-4">
```

Comment: What's wrong with `//div[@class="grid1-4"]/a/div/div/div/p/span`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This XPath:**

```
//div[@class="grid1-4"]//text()[contains(., 'Raised of')]
```

**Yields:**

```
52% Raised of $20,000 Goal
```